# How to archive watch kit app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect, watchkit, xcode6.3

My Apple watch app is now finished ! I'd like to archive it to submit it for iTunes validation. My problem is that I can archive the iPhone app, but no way to archive the whole project...

Do anyone know how to submit an iPhone app WITH its watch kit extension app ?

Have a great day !

Answer (score 5):

When you select Archive, your whole project is automatically archived (with all the extensions and the frameworks correctly configured).

Answer (score 1):

One thing it took me a while to figure out that might help: you need to select your project AND the "IOS Device" as target in order for your "Archive" option to be enabled. At that point, BalestraPatrick is correct that the WatchKit app compiles as well.

[image: Screen Shot of Project and Target Selection dialogue from Xcode 6.3.1]

Comment: You can also select "generic iOS Device" now.